# BigQuery ignore type mismatch

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to import hundreds of millions of records into bigquery. Their existing format is syslog, and I have manually convert them to newline delimited JSON files, which are gzipped.
In certain cases, a few rows contain data which does not fit to the SCHEMA's data-type (e.g. has the text "null" instead of being empty, while the field is an INTEGER).

There's only so much I can fix manually - we are talking about 30 days' worth of data, split into 1 hour files (--> 720 separate large files).

In the BQ documentation I saw that you can choose to ignore unknown fields. What about ignoring mis-matched data types? Is that possible? In planning?

I could tweak the maxBadRecords configuration, but in that case I will be missing entire records, not just some broken fields, and I'd rather not use this option if possible.

Comment: If you own the process that converts to json, is it an option to fix the type there? Or is it possible to do CSV instead?

Comment: It IS technically possible, but after struggling with schema issues for a few days, I'm honestly just worried that If i fix the specific "null" issue, I'll just run into a new problem immediately afterwards (as has happened in the past week, daily). The process of fixing the GZipped files take quite a long time.
If all else fails, I will use the maxBadRecords, I am just wondering if there's a better alternative.

Comment: In my experience CSV is more lenient than json for this kind of problem. Also you could import the whole json line as one field, and then parse json inside BigQuery. (Ingest the json file as CSV, and set a weird ASCII character as separator, so the whole line goes into one field)

Comment: I had thought of this method, but as a RECORD - which isn't relevant as it requires a known SCHEMA...
So you suggest inserting all as STRING, and then using regex to separate to key/value pairs and save the output as a table, which would auto-generate the schema... This is an interesting idea, I will try it!

Comment: There's also a JSON function, easier than regex!